# Is there a more elegant way to write generic static variables in Rust?

Tags: rust

Assume we have this struct:

```rust
struct A<T> {
    name: &'static str,
    call: &'static (dyn Fn(T) -> T + Sync),
    // and some other fields
}
```

And I would like to define a static object of `A` with different type parameters, like:

```
use num::Float;

static expf32: A<f32> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| f32::exp(x), /* some other fields */ };
static expf64: A<f64> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| f64::exp(x), /* some other fields */ };
static exp_big: A<BigDecimal> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| BigDecimal::exp(x), /* some other fields */ };
```

etc.

Is there a shorthand for these definitions? For example, something that looks like this:

```rust
static exp<T>: A<T> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| T::exp(x), /* some other fields */ }; //?
```

*My Ideas*: The closest method I came up with is to define a generic struct and put all the static members in its implementation:

```rust
use Num::Float;

struct Functions<T>;
impl<T: Float> Functions<T> {
    static exp: A<T> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| T::exp(x), /* some other fields */ }
}
```

But the compiler will report an error:

```
error: associated `static` items are not allowed
  --> src/terms/funcbase.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     pub static exp: SingleArgFuncBase<T> = SingleArgFuncBase {
13 | |         name: "exp",
14 | |         call: &|x| T::exp(x),
15 | |     };
   | |______^
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic `static`s are not allowed, because they are problematic to implement. But you can use a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! define_exp {
    {
        $( static $name:ident<$type:ty>; )+
    } => {
        $( static $name: A<$type> = A { name: "exp", call: &|x| <$type>::exp(x), /* some other fields */ }; )+
    };
}

define_exp! {
    static expf32<f32>;
    static expf64<f64>;
    static exp_big<BigDecimal>;
}
```